# When does marginal tightness imply joint tightness?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Suppose a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ converges in distribution to some probability measure $\mu_X$ on $\mathbb{R}$, and similarly $Y_n \stackrel{d}{\Rightarrow} \mu_Y$.

When is it true that $(X_n,Y_n)$ also converges in distribution? Or, more generally, when is $(X_n,Y_n)$ tight?

Comment: Properties of marginal distributions do not generally imply properties of joint distributions. Exceptions typically only occur in “obvious” cases such as when independence holds; or when X_n=Y_n always.

Comment: Seems like tightness always holds just by joint boundedness in probability. So there is always a subsequence that converges in distribution.

Comment: Counterexamples on convergence on the full sequence are easy: Let X be uniform over [-1,1] and define X_n=X for all n, Y_n=X if n even and Y_n=-X if n odd. Then marginals are always the same but joint distributions oscillate. Convergence on a subsequence is a deeper question.

Answer (score 2):

Tightness of marginals implies joint tightness in the product topology. This is readily seen from the definition of tightness, recalling that the product of two compacts is compact.

Answer (score 2):

If $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of Borel probability measures on $X \times X$ endowed with the product topology for a Polish space $X$, then compactness of the corresponding marginal sequences $(\mu_n^{(1)})_n$ and $(\mu_n^{(2)})_n$ implies tightness of  $(\mu_n)_{n\geq 1}$ as follows:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $K_i \subseteq X$ compact such that $\mu_n^{(i)}(K_i) \geq 1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (such sets exist by the assumed tightness of both marginal sequences). Then, $K_1 \times K_2 \subseteq X\times X$ is compact and for each $n \geq 1$:
$$\mu_n((K_1\times K_2)^c) \leq \mu_n(X\times K_2^c)+\mu_n(K_1^c \times X)=\mu_n^{(2)}(K_2^c)+\mu_n^{(1)}(K_1^c) \leq \epsilon.$$Hence, $(\mu_n)_n$ is tight.

This applies to your question by considering $\mu_n^{(1)} \sim X_n$, $\mu_n^{(2)} \sim Y_n$ and $\mu_n \sim (X_n,Y_n)$, noting that by your assumption both these marginal sequences are tight.

Comment: Of course, my answer is just a more detailed version of the answer above.